# Distinguishing device disconnects from timeouts

Tags: c, com, timeout, connection, serial-port

When using [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a communications resource it is possible to detect read timeouts by checking if less bytes than the requested amount of bytes were read. For example, when I want to read 1 byte, in case of a read timeout, 0 bytes are returned and the function succeeds.

However, when I disconnect the device (after reading some bytes) from the COM-Port and start a read operation on its old handle, the same thing happens: Function succeeds and says that 0 bytes were returned.

How can I distinguish between a device disconnect and a simple read timeout since no data is currently available?

Currently, I'm checking if 0 bytes were returned, and if yes, I check if the device is still connected using WMI. However, this does not look very clean and I hope that I can find a better solution here.

**Update**

Some more information about the device (as asked in comments):

```
dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
```

CTS and DSR are both set during data transfer and also after the device gets disconnected by unplugging the cable from the USB port.

Comment: You'd think it'd be a FILE_NOT_FOUND error or something...

Comment: You say you've disconnected the device and start a read operation on it's old handle. Are you disconnecting a USB to serial converter? In that case you'd get a read error. If you're disconnecting a cable from a serial port but the serial port stays connected to the PC then it's not an "old handle" - the handle is for the serial port which is still connected and therefore still valid. And you won't be able to do much in that case unless your device uses handshaking lines to indicate it is present, which you can also check to see if it is not present.

Comment: I read and while reading disconnect the device.

Comment: Yes, but how do you disconnect the device? Is it connected by a serial cable to a normal COM port or do you remove something which removes the COM port completely from the system?

Comment: The device is connected to a normal usb port on the pc. The port itself is not removed from the system.

Comment: OK. When the device is connected does it cause CTS or DSR to be set in the COM port? What about the state of those when it is disconnected? Can you edit your question to include the details of the device you are using please?

Comment: CTS and DSR are both set and remain set after the disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, you possibly need the [SetCommTimeoutsFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You should also check out the [othe communications functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for dealing with RS232.

**Edit:**  I had a very similar situation when moving some code from a hand-held device with an actual RS232, to one with a USB RS232.  Wobble the USB, and the port would get 'lost' unbeknownst to the application.  The code I wrote to get around this is as follows (Win32 platform)

```
COMMTIMEOUTS    CTO;
CTO.ReadIntervalTimeout = 500;
CTO.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 500;
CTO.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
if (SetCommTimeouts(hPort,&CTO) == 0)
{ 
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    if (dwError == 5)   
    {
        // Access denied, possibly loose USB, return error code or throw exception
        return Housten__We_have_a_problem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The `SetCommTimeouts` function makes it so that the `ReadFile` returns after 3 seconds if you specify a readtimeout of 3000ms there. However, the `ReadFile` will succeed and just return 0 bytes, as in the case where the device is not connected anymore. I don't know how the other communications functions could help me with my problem. Could you please specify what functions I should check out exactly?

Comment: The question is about a disconnect during a data transfer, not about initially connecting to the device. Or do you mean setting the timeouts everytime I read 0 and when it doesn't work it means disconnected?

Comment: The disconnect I was getting was during a data transfer.  Basically, on the mobile device, the USB was getting wobbled mid-transfer causing a disconnect, which had to be identified as different from a time-out.  Reason being that in my disconnect scenario, the port was lost, and it was necessary to close and re-open the handle.  In a time-out this obviously wasn't the case.

Comment: So, when you detect a timeout (readbytes == 0), you call the `SetCommTimeouts` function and if it fails with `ERR_ACCESS_DENIED` you detect the error.

Comment: Yup, the above code is part of a larger function to read from the port into a buffer.  In my case it i'm using C++ and throw an exception whenever GetLastError returns access denied on any functions using the port handle.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

On Linux, read and select also return 0, but `tcgetattr`, will return an error on disconnect and 0 on timeout, so that's one way to do it.